# How can I make an if statement that is dependent on the day of the week?

Tags: php, date, if-statement

I would like to make some code which has an `if` statement that uses some code on Sunday to Wednesday and other code Thursday to Saturday.

This is what I am starting with:

```
<?php
$t = date("H");

if ($t < "20") {
    echo "Have a good day!";
} else {
    echo "Have a good night!";
}
?>
```

How can I extend this to take the day of the week into account?

Comment: I is unclear what you are asking. Please see [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Is a switch ok?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$t = (int)date("w");

if ($t <= 3) {
    echo "Sunday to wedneday";
} else {
    echo "Thursday to Saturday";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would do it this way ( for readability, and future modification )

```
switch(date('l')){
   case 'Sunday':
   case 'Monday':
   case 'Tuesday':
   case 'Wednesday':
       //code for these days
   break;
   case 'Thursday':
   case 'Friday':
   case 'Saturday':
       //code for these days
   break;
}
```

It's very easy to see what this does "at a glance", often times that is the most important thing when programing.

Answer (score -1):

This should be your syntax

```
    if (($day == 'Sunday') || ($day == 'Monday') || ($day == 'Tuesday') || ($day == 'Wednesday')) {

      #Do something

    } else {

       #Do something else
    }
```

Comment: How does `$day` get populated?

Comment: Then You need to get the current day using PHP timestamp using the time function

`$current_time = time();`

Answer (score -1):

I'd access the numeric day

```
$dow = date('w'); // 0 is Sunday
if ($dow <= 3) {
    sundayToWednesday();
} else {
    thursdayToSaturday();
}
```

Comment: It is cowardly and unhelpful to downvote without a reason.